# how to use Objective-C project in my Swift project

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Note: I know [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24002369/6521116), but I don't know below,

I want to use this [EsptouchForIOS's Demo](https://github.com/EspressifApp/EsptouchForIOS) in my project. The demo is write in OC, it has a storyboard and controller. I want to know how to integrate the demo in my swift project, and use that storyboard and it's controller in my swift project.

Comment: Storyboards are not dependent of a language. You an use them from either Objective-C or Swift.

Comment: @the4kman Thank you. I want know how to integrate the oc demo in my swift project.

Comment: You need to create Objective-C bridging header file named as "ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h" where "ProjectName" is your Swift project and inside that file import the Objective-C header files that you want to expose to Swift.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'll start writing from the very beginning. Suppose you have a project in Objective-C and now you want to continue your project's development in Swift. Follow the below guidelines: (This intends to your specific needs)

First choose to add a new file from **File->New->File**. In this process select your language as **Swift**. In the final step here, you will be prompted to `Create Bridging Header`. Select that:

[image: Bridging Header creation]

Now build your project once (`⌘`+`B`). You may get an error like this:

[image: iOS SDK version error message]

Change your target's minimum deployment to the version that **Swift** supports. (Example in the below screenshot)
[image: Changing deployment target]

### To use Objective-C resources in Swift files:

Now that you've got one `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h` file in your project. If you want to use any Objective-C class in your Swift files, you just include the header file of that class in this bridging header file. Like in this project, you have `ESP_NetUtil` and `ESPViewController` class and their header files too. You want to expose them to Swift and use them later in Swift code. So import them in this bridging header file:

[image: Importing Objective-C header files in Bridging Header]

Build once again. Now you can go to your Swift file. And use the Objective-C classes as like you use any resource in swift. See:

[image: Objective-C classes used in Swift]

> **N.B: You must expose all the class headers (that you're intending to use later in Swift) in that bridging header file**

### To use Swift resources in Objective-C files:

Now you may wonder, I've successfully used Objective-C resources in Swift. What about the opposite? Yes! You can do the opposite too. Find your `Target->Build Settings->Swift Compiler - General->Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name`. This is the header file you will be using inside your Objective-C classes for any `Swift` to `Objective-C` interoperability. To know more check [here](https://www.codementor.io/codementorteam/swift-objective-c-using-2-languages-in-your-project-ucm16ki0l).

[image: Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name]

Now inside any of your Objective-C class, import that interface header and use Swift resources in Objective-C code:

[image: Import and using Swift resource in Objective-C]

You will get more understanding from the [official apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

> You can checkout the worked out version of your linked project [here](https://bitbucket.org/m-i-n/objective-c-swift-in-same-project) with `Objective-C`-`Swift` interoperability.

Comment: Thanks. It should be easier I think.

Answer (score 2):

So according to your question, you have added an objective C bridge in your swift project using [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift).

Now, import all headers (.h) files of your objective-c source code (demo project) that you want to direct use in swift file.

For example, your demo project has [EsptouchForIOS](https://github.com/EspressifApp/EsptouchForIOS) following header (file with extension .h) files in project source code.

`ESPAppDelegate.h, ESPDataCode.h, ESPTouchDelegate.h`

import a header file in your bridge, which you want to use in your swift code. Suppose in your swift code you want touch delegate `ESPTouchDelegate` then write,

```
#import "ESPTouchDelegate.h"
```

Here is snapshot of your demo integration in my Test Swift project with bridge

[image]

and import statements.

[image]

Now, there is function/method in an objective C file `getValue`

[image]

which is used/accessed in swift project/file.

[image]

Similarly, you can import as many files (source headers) as you want in bridge and use the same files (source code) in swift.

Comment: I really concenred is that how to use the storyboard and the controller of OC project in the Swift project.   So that I didn't to style the storyboard and write the event action for the event of storyboard in the swift project.     Sorry I'm new to ios, I don't if this is possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have never tried to use objective-c from swift project. But I normally used swift classes from my objective-c project. I usually follow this instructions https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html from apple developer website.